# Get string from dll in second window

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, get, set

I have a problem read string from a dll file. Below are some listings. I don't know why in window1 I get empty string. In MainWindow I can read from dll file. I want to read this string from dll in window2, window3 ... What to do?

Dll file,

```
namespace stringTest
{
    public class DllstringTest
    {
        string string1;
        public string testString
        {
            get
            {
                return this.string1;
            }

            set
            {
                this.string1 = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindow application,

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DllstringTest st = new DllstringTest();
        st.testString = "5";
        Window1 w1 = new Window1();
        w1.Show();
    }
}
```

Window1,

```
namespace stringTest_app
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DllstringTest st1 = new DllstringTest();
            MessageBox.Show(st1.testString);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with it being a dll, you are creating two *new* instances of `DllstringTest`, you need to pass this between forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use static variables. The problem you are facing at the moment is that you have two different class instances.

The solution would be to create a single static `DllstringTest` variable and use it across your application.

Comment: using static variables for this is a terrible idea IMO

Comment: @Sayse: I did not manage to finish my answer before you wrote a comment. As I said, either he will have static variables in his dll or he can create single static instance of DllstringTest class and use it across the application.

Comment: static anything for this is a bad idea, the variable should confined to its scope. On top of this, this is a training exercise for the OP so bad habits should not  be encouraged.

Comment: @Sayse: Static variables aren't a sin, it is just good to know when to use them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using separate instances of your `DllstringTest`. You cannot set a value in one instance and have it magically set all future instances. (Well technically you could but it isn't what you want to do, and it wouldn't be magic either)

You could use a static class is you only ever want a single instance:

```
public static class DllstringTest
{
    public static string testString { get;set; }
}
```

which you can access like so:

```
DllstringTest.testString
```

OR (**probably a better approach**) you could pass your instance from your main form to your other forms:

```
//IN MainWindow
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DllstringTest st = new DllstringTest();
    st.testString = "5";
    Window1 w1 = new Window1();
    w1.DllInstance = st;
    w1.Show();
}

//IN Window1
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public DllstringTest DllInstance { get;set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(DllInstance.testString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject st into window1 via the constructor:

MainWindow application

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DllstringTest st = new DllstringTest();
        st.testString = "5";
        Window1 w1 = new Window1(st);
        w1.Show();
    }
}
}
```

Window1:

```
namespace stringTest_app
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private DllstringTest st;
    public Window1(DllstringTest st)
    {
        this.st = st;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //DllstringTest st1 = new DllstringTest();
        MessageBox.Show(this.st.testString);

    }
}
```

}